# Get proper intellisense with overloaded multimethods in python

Tags: python, overloading, intellisense, multiple-dispatch, multimethod

The following code works as expected:

```py
from multimethod import multimethod

@multimethod
def foo(a: int):
    print(f"only {a}")

@multimethod
def foo(a: int, b: int):
    print(f"{a} and {b}")

foo(1)
foo(1, 2)
```

Output:

```
only 1
1 and 2
```

However, the Intellisense in VSCode for the function arguments look like this

[image: intellisense]

I know that this is caused by the multimethod decorator expecting any number of arguments for it to decide which overload of the function to call, however what I want is something like this:

[image]

with multiple argument lists.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Someone will have to add type annotations to the multimethods library, either to the code itself or as stubs.

Comment: Although, I don't think Python's type system would be able to handle this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hmmmmm, then is there any way of getting proper intellisense on overloaded functions? Overloaded functions from lots of modules seem to support this feature and their parameter info shows multiple overloads, how do they do it?

Comment: So, to be clear, Python *doesn't have function overloading* at the language level. It is always implemented in some way manually (e.g. by using this library).  SO it isn't clear by what you mean exactly with "overloaded funtions from lots of modules". There is a concept of overloading for *type annotations*, which I suspect is what you mean. But again, **that requires the library to be annotated or provided annotated stubs*. Furthermore, I'm not sure that you would be able to do this for a library like `multimethod`, which is using the very dynamic features of python to accomplish this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What I mean by overloading in this case is multiple dispatching. But I see, I just wish there is a way to write multiple dispatch functions while also getting intellisense on them.

Comment: So, that's what I mean, when you see that in lots of modules, you almost certainly aren't seeing multiple distpatch. Generally, through a combination of accepting optional paramters and/ or using `*args`/`**kwargs`, that logic is handled internally in a function. For functions that do that, you can *type hint* it as having `typing.overload`, so that *third party static analysis tools can use that info*, but the language itself has no overloading/multiple dispatch (unless implemented manually)

Comment: you could write a stubs file for your `foo` function using `typing.overload` though, that might be one approach. I don't have my keyboard with me at the momement to cook up an examples... but stub files are supported with pylance for vscode, which I assume you are using

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "you almost certainly aren't seeing multiple distpatch" Ahhhh I see, I thought they were. Thank you for clarifying that. Regardless, I just checked out how stub files work and it implemented it, it works for my purpose.

Comment: great! you can add that as an answer to your own question! You can ask/answer/accept your own questions, that's totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @juanpa.arrivillaga I solved this by creating a stub file alongside the file that contains the functions, this worked perfectly. Although my actual code is different from this, the stub file for the example `foo` function would look like this:

foo.pyi

```py
from typing import overload

@overload
def foo(a: int): ...
@overload
def foo(a: int, b: int): ...
```

This will provide whatever editor you're using (i.e. VSCode) with the information to display parameter info of both overloads.